# Add AWS EC2 instance to existing Availability Group

Tags: availability-groups, aws

I currently have an AG with 2 replicas both running SQL Server 2016. These are both located on premise. I was looking to add a third node using a AWS EC2 instance and asynchronous replication.

Networking issues aside, is this an acceptable approach?

The only resources I can find on the internet appear to use distributed AGs but that would mean having a second EC2 instance in AWS

Answer (score 0):

I assume it would be like this [hybrid it: disaster recovery scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-high-availability-dr#hybrid-it-disaster-recovery-solutions) but with AWS instead of Azure. There is an interesting point in the article about having your Active Directory available in the cloud.

I think you'd have to give some thought to how quorum would work. For example, what would happen if you did a manual failover to the cloud instance, then later your on-premises instances came back online?

HTH